# Como llamar a funcion desde otra funcion, con ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

```
 var vm = this;
            vm.dt_data = [];               
            vm.item = {};
            vm.edit = edit;
            vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                .withOption('initComplete', function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $compile($('.dt-uikit .md-input'))($scope);
                    })
                })
                .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
                .withOption('createdRow', function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                    $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
                })
                .withOption('ajax', {
                    dataSrc: function(json) {
                        json['draw']=1
                        json['recordsFiltered'] = json.records.length                            
                        json['recordsTotal'] =json.records.length
                        console.log(json)
                        return json.records;
                      },
                    url: 'http://localhost:808/sistemadrp/public/ws/usuarios',
                    type: 'GET',
                })
                //.withDataProp('records')
                .withOption('processing', true)
                .withOption('serverSide', true);

            vm.dtColumns = [
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('Id'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('usuario').withTitle('Usuario'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('nombre').withTitle('Nombre'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('email').withTitle('Email'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('telefono').withTitle('Telefono'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('estado').withTitle('Estado'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('created_at').withTitle('Creado'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Acciones').notSortable().renderWith(function(data,type,full){
                  vm.item[data.id] = data; 
                    return  ' <a href="#" data-uk-modal="{target:\'#modal_header_footer\'}" ng-click="showCase.edit(showCase.item[' + data.id + '])">'+
                            ' <i class="md-icon material-icons md-bg-light-blue-900 uk-text-contrast"></i></a>'+
                            ' <a href="#" data-uk-modal="{target:\'#modal_header_footer_eliminar\'}" ng-click="showCase.edit(showCase.item[' + data.id + '])">'+
                            ' <i class="md-icon material-icons md-bg-red-900 uk-text-contrast">&#xE872;</i></a>';
              })                    
          ];
```

De esta manera funciona la tabla, tenia el problema que los botones generados por cada registro no entraba a la funcion por no hacer uso de `$compile`, debia agregar lo siguiente por cada fila que va creando:

```
.withOption('createdRow', function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
            })
```

incluso Mando a llamar un modal y le mando la data para hacer uso de ng-model en el modal.

La tabla queda asi:

```
<table datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions"  dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" class="uk-table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero necesitas corregir esto:

> ```
> function actionsHtml(data, type, full, meta){
>             vm.usuario[data.id] = data; 
>             return ' <a href="#" data-uk-modal="{target:\'#modal_header_footer\'}" ng-click="editar()"><i class="md-icon material-icons md-bg-light-blue-900 uk-text-contrast"></i></a>'+
>                    ' <a href="#" data-uk-modal="{target:\'#modal_header_footer_eliminar\'}"><i class="md-icon material-icons md-bg-red-900 uk-text-contrast">&#xE872;</i></a>';               
>       }
> ```

Si puedes fijarte agregue el cierre de la etiqueta HTML

Comment: es cierto, ya lo corregi. Pero aun asi no llama a la funcion :/

Comment: La función editar requiere un parámetro `usuario`, intenta pasar un valor `ng-click="editar(1)"`

Comment: ya pase el valor, aun asi nada.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código completo ?

Comment: acaba de agregarlo

Comment: la función editar declara la de esta forma `$scope.editar = function(usuario){ console.log(usuario); };`

Comment: ya lo hice asi, y nada.